# Fill std::string directly from C API

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I find myself writing c++ wrappers around C style APIs pretty frequently, and a common bit of wasteful code I write goes like this:

```
//getSomeString() wraps C api that gets some C string from somewhere
std::string MyClass::getSomeString()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_MAX];
    memset(buffer, '\0', BUFFER_MAX);
    auto result = GetCApiString(buffer, BUFFER_MAX); //C style string getter 
    return (result == NO_ERROR) ? std::string{buffer} : ""; //Copy here
}
```

But I'd really like to do something like this:

```
//getSomeString(): as before
std::string MyClass::getSomeString()
{
    DirectStringFillIterator<char> returnString; // <--HERE. Is something like this possible?
    auto result = GetCApiString(returnString, BUFFER_MAX);
    return (result == NO_ERROR) ? returnString.str() : ""; 
}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: If you're wrapping around C code that returns `NULL` it's often better to map C errors to C++ exceptions. This avoids having to return garbage empty strings. In other languages like Rust or Swift you can encapsulate the result as an "Optional", where you can test if it contains a value or not, but C++ is really not as open to such concepts.

Comment: @tadman - Not open? There's `boost::optional`. And the soon to be here `std::optional` as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, that's good to see. I mean "open" as in Swift's implicit unwrap semantics with `!`. Maybe "ideal" is a better word.

Comment: @Jodocus: how would that solve anything? If you have a local buffer returning a `string_view` to it would just open the door to undefined behavior...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::string` is guaranteed to be contiguous since C++11 (but it's such even in C++03 on every implementation I've ever met). So, usually you can just do

```
std::string MyClass::getSomeString() {
    std::string ret(BUFFER_MAX, '\0');
    if(GetCApiString(&ret[0], ret.size()) != NO_ERROR) return "";
    ret.resize(ret.find_first_of(0));
    return ret;
}
```

This avoid one copy over your first method (from local buffer to the returned string), but forces the returned string to allocate `BUFFER_MAX` bytes always, which may or may not be a downside in your cases.

Comment: Oh, that's excellent. Very simple idea that I have overlooked. Thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as solved as soon as I can.

Comment: Rather than `&ret[0]` I personally prefer `ret.data()`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: for some idiotic reason, `std::string::data()` returns a `const char *`, exactly as `c_str()`. `std::vector<T>::data()`, instead, returns a plain modifiable `T*` (although I end up using often `&ref[0]` even for `vector`, as I never remember if it's `vector` or `string` the one with the stupid `const`).

Comment: @MatteoItalia A new non-`const` overload will be added in C++17 (for `.data()`, not `.c_str()`).

Comment: @Holt: well, that's about time! :-)

Comment: There is no std::string constructor just taking a count, need to at least pass a char too such as `std::string ret(BUFFER_MAX, '\0')`.

Comment: @Zitrax: thank you, fixed; I was probably thinking about `std::vector`'s constructors when writing that example.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: ok, that's more embarassing, it was a brainfart but resulted in a subtle logic error; I hope the people using this code bothered to actually check the results before copy-pasting...

Comment: It might also be an idea to run `ret.shrink_to_fit()`after the resize to free that extra capacity (unless you plan to append to that string later).